# How can I theme profile field forms in an HTML table?

Tags: forms, theming, users

I put this code in Drupal 6, and made a template file called "user-register.tpl.php" to override the default registration page.

```
function my_theme_theme(){
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user-register',
    ),
  );
}
```

With this, I could print profile user name, email and password.

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); // prints the username field ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['mail']); // print the email field ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); // print the password field ?>
```

This code doesn't print the profile field form.

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['profile_category_name']['profile_field_name'] ); ?>
```

Ideally I would like to print the form itself separately from the title, and the description so that I can arrange them with `<table>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it didn't work. Because my category name was not ASCII characters and it now works after changing them to ASCII characters with the code above.